# Remove blacklisted terms from string then eliminate unnecessary spaces

Tags: php, replace, sanitization, blacklist

I have an array of blacklisted terms:

```
$arrayBlacklist = array("Kota","Kab.","Kota Administrasi","KAB", "KOTA", "Kabupaten");
```

and I have a string to sanitize:

```
$city = "Kota Jakarta Selatan";
// also: "Kab. Jakarta Selatan", "Kota Administrasi Jakarta Selatan", ...
```

I just want to remove the `$arrayBlacklist` value if it's in the `$city` variable.

So, I get `$city = "Jakarta Selatan"`

Comment: You want to handle spaces as well?

Comment: Yes,.. @vivek_23

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Sort the array based on string length to avoid overlapping issues using [`usort`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php).
- [`preg_replace`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php) each of the string in a *case-insensitive* manner.
- Finally, remove all double spaces with a single space using [`str_replace`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php).

**Snippet:**

```
<?php

$arrayBlacklist = array("Kota","Kab.","Kota Administrasi","KAB", "KOTA", "Kabupaten","Jakarta");

usort($arrayBlacklist,function($a,$b){
    return strlen($b) <=> strlen($a);
});


$city = "Kota Jakarta Selatan kota Administrasi ki";
$city = " ". $city. " "; // add spaces to ease the matching

foreach($arrayBlacklist as $val){
   $city = preg_replace('/\s'.$val.'\s/i','  ',$city); // replace with double spaces to avoid recursive matching
}

$city = str_replace("  "," ",trim($city));
echo $city;
```

**Update:**

The `preg_replace` matches the strings as a string covered by space on both left and right hand sides since you sometimes have non-word characters too in your blacklisted strings. To ease the matching, we deliberately add leading and trailing spaces before the start of the loop.

**Note:** We replace the matched string in `preg_replace` with double spaces to avoid recursive matching with other strings.

Comment: if we put \b in preg_replace, and then we change the value of $city to "Kab. Jakarta Selatan", We got ". Jakarta Selatan". but when we dont add \b in preg_replace, the problem is gone,..

Comment: @MuamarHumaidi Selatan on which input?

Comment: if $city = "Kab. Jakarta Selatan", and using  $city = preg_replace('/\s'.$val.'\s/i','  ',$city);  will get 'Selatan' only,...  @vivek_23

Comment: @MuamarHumaidi It will cause issues, trust me. Also, on which input you got a wrong output?

Comment: @MuamarHumaidi That is because `Jakarta` is in my blacklist array. Remove it as per your demand.

Comment: @MuamarHumaidi Did you get it? The current code works fine.

Comment: $arrayBlacklist = array("Kota","Kab.","Kota Administrasi","KAB.", "KOTA", "Kabupaten");
usort($arrayBlacklist,function($a,$b){
    return strlen($b) <=> strlen($a);
});
$city = "Kab. Jakarta Selatan";
foreach($arrayBlacklist as $val){
    $city = preg_replace('/'.$val.'/i','',$city);
}
$city = str_replace("  "," ",trim($city));
echo $city;

Its Done sir using your first answer ,...

Comment: @MuamarHumaidi The first version had bugs. The current version is correct. You can see in the link that this works http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/f1f4d67421dbe8d5a9c498afe8be3bbdf56de314

Answer (score 3):

```
$arrayBlacklist = array("Kota Administrasi", "Kota","Kab.","KAB", "KOTA", "Kabupaten");
rsort($arrayBlacklist);
$city = "Kota Jakarta Selatan";
        
$city = trim(preg_replace('/\s+/', ' ',str_replace($arrayBlacklist, '', $city)));
```

You can use
https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php

**str_replace** can use arrays as search and replace statements.

Comment: Trim spaces after removing. Edit: one more, need to address this as well: if Jakarta was removed `"Kota Jakarta Selatan"` the resulting string would have double space between the words. `"Kota  Selatan"`

Comment: but when i change value of $city = "Kota Administrasi Jakarta Selatan", its only Removed "Kota",.. when a print $city i just get "Administrasi Jakarta Selatan",... ?

Comment: The better way is to clarify `arrayBlacklist`. You can split `Kota Administrasi` to several values, or replace just with Administrasi`

Comment: @MuamarHumaidi i just realised that this is a nice little agorithm problem. V-K I do not agree. Sometimes you might not want to remove `Administrasi` alone, only remove `Kota Administrasi`

Comment: there is another way to solve it, just put longets parts at the start of array `$arrayBlacklist`

Comment: Yes,  @V-K  When i put the longest part at the star of the array it solved,...

Comment: @V-K I think you should edit the answer to sort the original array based on value length. (`usort` maybe) and then add a `preg_replace` to remove double spaces on the final string.

Comment: `rsort()` is different from sorting based on length.

Comment: but it's enough to sort array with values like `"Kota Administrasi"`, `"Kota"`. The longest one will always first

Comment: @V-K Are you sure longest will be always first? http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/734d4a27bb4485a4d5359b807e3affb7bb3af1fe

Comment: I think your example is not actual. You compare the world and symbol, but we need to compare word and phrase with the same word.

Comment: @V-K Not really, that isn't the context of the question.

Answer (score 0):

Less elegant than other answer, but gets the job done.

```
$arrayBlacklist = ['Kota', 'Kab.', 'Kota Administrasi', 'KAB', 'KOTA', 'Kabupaten'];
$city = 'Kota Jakarta Selatan'; 

// make an array of words from the city name
$cityAsArray = explode(' ', $city);

foreach ($cityAsArray as $key => $part) {
    // check if word is in blacklist
    if (in_array($part, $arrayBlacklist)) {
        // remove from the array if it is blacklisted
        unset($cityAsArray[$key]);
    }
}

// convert the city name back to string
$city = implode(' ', $cityAsArray);
```

**UPDATE:**
we can sort the blacklist array based on number of words, then string replacing each blacklisted string.

```
$arrayBlacklist = ["Kota", "Kab.", "Kota Administrasi", "KAB", "KOTA", "Kabupaten"];
$city = 'Kota Administrasi Jakarta Selatan';
usort($arrayBlacklist, function ($a, $b) {
    return substr_count($a, ' ') < substr_count($b, ' ');
});

foreach ($arrayBlacklist as $blacklist) {
    $city = trim(str_replace($blacklist, '', $city));
}
```

Comment: @MuamarHumaidi How does this solve `"Kota Administrasi Jakarta Selatan"` problem mentioned in your comment to the answer below?

Comment: Yes, Still Dont work ,.. So sorry ,... If  $city has "Kota Administrasi" ,...

Comment: Maybe add a preg_replace on the final string to tackle double spaces in the middle? PS: I do not want to post a new answer cos I think improving the existing answers is better.

Comment: `return substr_count($a, ' ') < substr_count($b, ' ');` this comparison looks incorrect. It's not about substrings but length of it.

Comment: it is counting the occurence of  `'  '` in each blacklisted string (how many words are inside). My logic was to sort the blacklisted array based on word count.

Comment: Word count and length of the word are not same.

Comment: @vivek_23 where did I mention length of word?

Comment: that's not a fact, it's implied CORRECTION, implied (sorry English is not my first language)

Comment: @MehrdadDastgir Apparently, it's a fact. The answer in the link should give an empty string but yours gave `abg` http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/8e5133231efaee163581a8de0da403474fb02943

Comment: I disagree, answer is based on given dataset `$arrayBlacklist = ["Kota", "Kab.", "Kota Administrasi", "KAB", "KOTA", "Kabupaten"];` and not random chars

Answer (score 0):

I think `strtr()` is the best tool for this job because:

1. You don't need to pre-sort your blacklist array
2. Longer matches will supersede shorter matches when replacing.

So effectively, you "translate", then trim leading/trailing spaces, then remove any internal redundant spaces.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/PIiAq))

```
$arrayBlacklist = ["Kota Administrasi", "Kota","Kab.","KAB", "KOTA", "Kabupaten"];
$trans = array_fill_keys($arrayBlacklist, '');

$cities = [
    "Kota Jakarta Selatan",
    "Kota Administrasi Selatan",
    "Kab. What Kota Kab.",
    "KOTA Kota Coca Cola",
];
        
foreach ($cities as $city) {
    var_export(
        preg_replace('/\s{2,}/', ' ', trim(strtr($city, $trans)))
    );
    echo "\n";
}
```

Output:

```
'Jakarta Selatan'
'Selatan'
'What'
'Coca Cola'
```